# save image from image tag <img> using POST service call using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, post

Am trying to save image from image tag

i have tried like file upload method

but it not working ,

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var imageUrl = info.ImageUri + '/Upload?imagePath=' + imagePath + '&imageName=' + imagename + '&imageSize=' + imagesize;
        var imageFileUri;
        request.open('POST', imageUrl);
        request.send(imgFile.files[0]);
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                if (request.status == 200) {
```

is there any way to save image which is already displaying in the image tag?

Comment: Do you mean you want to using the AJAX to upload the image file and also the image info?

Comment: what is your html code?data of your image is base64 encodeing?

Comment: yes, using the AJAX i want to upload the image file

Answer (score 2):

You can get the base64 string from the image.

html:

```
<img src="http://some/image/source" id="myImage"/>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:none;"/>
```

js:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
var imgString = c.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
       imageString: imgString
    }
    url: "/route/to/store/my/image",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

and in server side make an image from base64 string and store it with a file name. :)

Comment: while converting  base64 string to image it shows error, i working according to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565687/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-image-binary-file-and-save-onto-server

Answer (score 0):

this code is part of jquery ui plugin that i wrote time ago. requires jquery,

```
var self=this;
    if(!self._chMaxSize(self)){
        dialogMsg("Max file is " + self.maxMb + "Mb", "Error", null);
        return;
    }
    var msg="";

    $.each(self.savingFiles, function(index, file) {
            msg+="<br>Sending... " + file.name + " ";
            var fd = new FormData();
              fd.append("file", file);
              fd.append("idRef", idRef);


              $.ajax({
                      xhr: function() {
                        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

                        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                          if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                            percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                            $("#msg").html(msg +percentComplete + "%");
                          }
                        }, false);

                        return xhr;
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'fileUpload.htm',
                    data: fd,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:  function (data) {
                        msg+="<br> "+ data.result.msg;
                        $("#msg").html(msg);
                        $("#msg").addClass("ui-state-highlight");
                    }, error: function(data){
                        $("#msg").html("Transfer File Error.");
                        $("#msg").addClass("ui-state-error");
                    }
              });


     });
```